# Are slash commands suitable for non-tech users of enterprise software

Tags: user-behavior, novice-users, industrial-design

More and more user interfaces seem to offer technical commands and shortcuts like

- `/remind` (Slack)
- `/away` (Teams)
- `/assign` (Gitlab)
  ...

I was wondering if I should introduce such shortcuts in the graphical user interface of our industry software as well. I personally really like them but I fear that they are way too technical for non computer science - oriented people.

Is my fear legitimate? Is there any data on how such commands are used by non-technical users like accounting, human resources, designers, ... ?

Comment: I would say these are not intuitive solutions for your user group.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right, I would try to understand the context of your software. Is this an unnecessary flourish that a button or link could easily fulfil? Are these people power users that would benefit from such a shortcut?

I would recommend conducting some real-world research, ask people what their expectations are if they do such an action.

If you find that there is a real user benefit for having this feature I would look to notion.so for guidance on how you might explain the functionality (see attached screenshot)

[image]

[image]